# how to alter data on specific tables in standby postgres server

Tags: postgresql

I have a warm-standby postgres server and I store some information about the server itself in the database. So, the information kept in this table should be different between the primary and standby. However, once it is set to standby mode these values can no longer be updated. Is there any way to set specific tables/schemas to be writable while in standby mode?

Comment: If you are talking about a physical standby using streaming replication (or WAL shipping), then no, you can't make the standby writable.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help a_horse_with_no_name